# How to grab text from anonymous MenuItem in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, menu, menuitem

My goal is to create MenuItems from an ArrayList, and then add an event to each menuitem that searches the arraylist for the selected menuitem so that it can be transferred over to the next scene. The menu items will be inside a menu button.

```
    MenuButton selectAccount = new MenuButton("Select an Account");
    selectAccount.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

    for (int i = 0; i < accountList.size(); i++) {

        //add the items. accountList is my arraylist
        selectAccount.getItems().add(new MenuItem(accountList.get(i).getName()));

        //add the event to items.
        selectAccount.getItems().get(i).setOnAction((ActionEvent e)->{

         // need to grab the text that is inside the menuitem here
         // will run loop to compare text with names in my accountList arraylist
         // if name matches, then the object from arraylist will be loaded into next scene

        });
    }
```

The trouble I'm having is figuring out how to pull the text from the Menu items. How do I reference the text of these anonymous menu items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the type of the elements in `accountList` is a class `Account` (just change it accordingly if not), if you use the normal list iteration (instead of an index-based for loop), this all works perfectly naturally:

```
MenuButton selectAccount = new MenuButton("Select an Account");
selectAccount.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

for (Account account : accountList) {

    MenuItem item = new MenuItem(account.getName());
    selectAccount.getItems().add(item);

    item.setOnAction((ActionEvent e)->{

        // now just do whatever you need to do with account, e.g.
        showAccountDetails(account);

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I feel stupid. I need to get into the habit of using advanced for loops. My issue was coming from not switching get(i) to get(k) in my Events for loop.

Comment: @Adam Even without the for-each style loop (I actually think of that as *less* "advanced" than index-based looping), you can still just do `Account account = accountList.get(i);` at the beginning of the loop, then the code looks the same as in my answer. There's never any need to iterate through the list in the event handler.

Comment: Nice. Thank you!